# How to limit the textfield entry to 2 decimal places in swift 4?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a textfield and  I want to limit the entry to max 2 decimal places.

number like 12.34 is allowed but not 12.345

How do I do it?

Comment: Use `UITextFieldDelegate`'s `shouldChangeCharactersIn` + round the decimals to X places

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Set your controller as the delegate for the text field and check if the proposed string satisfy your requirements:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    textField.delegate = self
    textField.keyboardType = .decimalPad
}

func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard let oldText = textField.text, let r = Range(range, in: oldText) else {
        return true
    }

    let newText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: r, with: string)
    let isNumeric = newText.isEmpty || (Double(newText) != nil)
    let numberOfDots = newText.components(separatedBy: ".").count - 1

    let numberOfDecimalDigits: Int
    if let dotIndex = newText.index(of: ".") {
        numberOfDecimalDigits = newText.distance(from: dotIndex, to: newText.endIndex) - 1
    } else {
        numberOfDecimalDigits = 0
    }

    return isNumeric && numberOfDots <= 1 && numberOfDecimalDigits <= 2
}
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked very well. can you suggest some source where I can learn this? I am using 'ios programming' from big nerd ranch. it doesn't teach it.

Comment: No book can cover everything. That Big Nerd Ranch book is a very good intro into Swift and iOS programming. Programming is continuous learning. You will find the missing pieces from other books or at websites like StackOverflow :)

Comment: how do I permit minus sign in the textfield to enter negative doubles?

Comment: Be careful with "." though, that's the correct character to look for in English locale. In many other languages that will be ",".

Instead of the fixed string, you should check for NSLocale.current.decimalSeparator

Comment: Notice that when the user starts typing with . it cancels the typing, it's an edge case but still a thing to consider

Comment: @CodeDifferent can you explain why you needed the first line?

Answer (score 6):

In Swift 4.

TextField have 10 digit limit and after decimal 2 digit limit (you can change the Limits). The dot will allow only one time in the textField.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate {

    var dotLocation = Int()

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {


        let nonNumberSet = CharacterSet(charactersIn: "0123456789.").inverted

        if Int(range.length) == 0 && string.count == 0 {
            return true
        }

        if (string == ".") {
            if Int(range.location) == 0 {
                return false
            }
            if dotLocation == 0 {
                dotLocation = range.location
                return true
            } else {
                return false
            }
        }

        if range.location == dotLocation && string.count == 0 {
            dotLocation = 0
        }

        if dotLocation > 0 && range.location > dotLocation + 2 {
            return false
        }

        if range.location >= 10 {

            if dotLocation >= 10 || string.count == 0 {
                return true
            } else if range.location > dotLocation + 2 {
                return false
            }

            var newValue = (textField.text as NSString?)?.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)
            newValue = newValue?.components(separatedBy: nonNumberSet).joined(separator: "")
            textField.text = newValue

            return false

        } else {
            return true
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

**Guys, here's the solution:**

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        let dotString = "."

        if let text = textField.text {
            let isDeleteKey = string.isEmpty

            if !isDeleteKey {
                if text.contains(dotString) {
                    if text.components(separatedBy: dotString)[1].count == 2 {

                                return false

                    }

                }

            }
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Only Two decimal point allow and only one "." allow

```
 func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {

                    let text: NSString = textField.text! as NSString
                    let resultString = text.replacingCharacters(in: range, with: string)


        //Check the specific textField 
         if textField == costTextField {
             let textArray = resultString.components(separatedBy: ".")
             if textArray.count > 2 { //Allow only one "."
                return false
             }
           if textArray.count == 2 {
              let lastString = textArray.last
             if lastString!.count > 2 { //Check number of decimal places 
                   return false
               }
            }
          }
           return true
       }
```

Comment: Thanks, It's worked for me. I need to ask you that how I can restrict the user to don't add point without any digit. eg (.10) or just (.) in price field.

Answer (score 2):

None of the answers handled the decimalSeparator and all the edge cases I came across so I decided to write my own.

```
extension YourController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard let text = textField.text, let decimalSeparator = NSLocale.current.decimalSeparator else {
            return true
        }

         var splitText = text.components(separatedBy: decimalSeparator)
         let totalDecimalSeparators = splitText.count - 1
         let isEditingEnd = (text.count - 3) < range.lowerBound

         splitText.removeFirst()

         // Check if we will exceed 2 dp
         if
             splitText.last?.count ?? 0 > 1 && string.count != 0 &&
             isEditingEnd
         {
             return false
         }

         // If there is already a dot we don't want to allow further dots
         if totalDecimalSeparators > 0 && string == decimalSeparator {
             return false
         }

         // Only allow numbers and decimal separator
         switch(string) {
         case "", "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", decimalSeparator:
             return true
         default:
             return false
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Following the [Code Different's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45450041/6282606), I've improved the code to support a different Locale and different UITextFields in the same class.

```
  func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    guard textField.keyboardType == .decimalPad, let oldText = textField.text, let r = Range(range, in: oldText) else {
        return true
    }

    let newText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: r, with: string)
    let isNumeric = newText.isEmpty || (Double(newText) != nil)

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = Locale.current
    let decimalPoint = formatter.decimalSeparator ?? "."
    let numberOfDots = newText.components(separatedBy: decimalPoint).count - 1

    let numberOfDecimalDigits: Int
    if let dotIndex = newText.index(of: ".") {
        numberOfDecimalDigits = newText.distance(from: dotIndex, to: newText.endIndex) - 1
    } else {
        numberOfDecimalDigits = 0
    }
    return isNumeric && numberOfDots <= 1 && numberOfDecimalDigits <= 2
  }
```

Comment: FWIW, we don’t generally use `NS` classes in our Swift code unless we have to. Thus, the `formatter.locale = NSLocale.current` could be `formatter.locale = Locale.current` or `formatter.locale = .current` or omitted entirely, because it defaults to the current locale.

Comment: I noticed 2 issues: (1) `(Double(newText) != nil)` will never work if the user is inputting an amount with a , separator. (2) `newText.index(of: ".")` should be `newText.firstIndex(of: Character(decimalPoint))`

Answer (score 1):

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
            let dotString = "."

            if let text = textField.text {
                let isDeleteKey = string.isEmpty

                if !isDeleteKey {
                    if text.contains(dotString) {
                        if text.components(separatedBy: dotString)[1].count == 2 {

                                    return false

                        }

                    }

                }
            }
            return true
         }
```

Comment: What if someone is using Locale.current.decimalSeparator to find the decimal convention being used in a particular locale

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5. Adding to Enrique's answer (based on Code Different baseline), I found the need to allow the Delete key to operate anywhere on the line along with a sign (+ or -) or decimal point at the beginning of the input line.

```
func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
    // Limit number fields to +/- Real #s: sign as first character, one decimal separator, one decimal place after separator
    if string.isEmpty { return true }   // Allow delete key anywhere!
    guard let oldText = textField.text, let rng = Range(range, in: oldText) else {
        return true
    }
    let newText = oldText.replacingCharacters(in: rng, with: string)

    let isNumeric = newText.isEmpty || (Double(newText) != nil)

    let formatter = NumberFormatter()
    formatter.locale = .current
    let decimalPoint = formatter.decimalSeparator ?? "."
    let numberOfDots = newText.components(separatedBy: decimalPoint).count - 1

    let numberOfDecimalDigits: Int
    if let dotIndex = newText.firstIndex(of: ".") {
        numberOfDecimalDigits = newText.distance(from: dotIndex, to: newText.endIndex) - 1
    } else {
        numberOfDecimalDigits = 0
    }
    if newText.count == 1 && !isNumeric {   // Allow first character to be a sign or decimal point
        return CharacterSet(charactersIn: "+-" + decimalPoint).isSuperset(of: CharacterSet(charactersIn: string))
    }
    return isNumeric && numberOfDots <= 1 && numberOfDecimalDigits <= 1
}
```